Attributes in new order email
I am trying to modify the template of the new ordern shipment, so that besides the column of name and quantity, also appears the column of attribute "color" and attribute "priority".
I was able to create the columns and they appear without any problem but I can't connect the information to appear.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$text_align  = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
$margin_side = is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right';

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
    $product       = $item->get_product();
    $sku           = '';
    $purchase_note = '';
    $image         = '';
        $color         = $product->get_attribute( 'color' );
        $prioridad     = $product->get_attribute( 'prioridad' );

    if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
        $sku           = $product->get_sku();
        $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note();
        $image         = $product->get_image( $image_size );
                $Color         = $product->get_attribute( 'color' )
                $Prioridad     = $product->get_attribute( 'prioridad' )
    }

    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;">
        <?php

        // Show title/image etc.
        if ( $show_image ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', $image, $item ) );
        }

        // Product name.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ) );
        // color.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product->get_attribute( 'color' ), $item, false ) );      // prioridad.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product->get_attribute( 'prioridad' ), $item, false ) );


Can you elaborate on what you mean by, "I can't connect the information to appear"? Where are you expecting information to appear? Is any information appearing? If the information is wrong, how?
